# Spring Security With X.509 Certificate

Tags: java, spring-security, x509certificate

I am slowly going insane trying to configure Spring Security 3.0.0 to secure an application.

I have configured the server (jetty) to require client authentication (using a smart card). However, I cannot seem to get the applicationContext-security.xml and UserDetailsService implementation right.

First, from the application context file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">


<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:x509 subject-principal-regex="CN=(.*?)," user-service-ref="accountService" />
</security:http>

<bean id="accountService" class="com.app.service.AccountServiceImpl"/>
```

The UserDetailsService looks like this:

```
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService, UserDetailsService {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AccountServiceImpl.class);

private AccountDao accountDao;

@Autowired
public void setAccountDao(AccountDao accountDao) {
    this.accountDao = accountDao;
}

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

    log.debug("called loadUserByUsername()");
    System.out.println("called loadByUsername()");
    
    Account result = accountDao.getByEdpi(s);
    return result;

}
```

}

The application has a "front page" with a Login button, so access to that should not require any sort of authentication.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The application has a "front page" with a Login button, so access to that should not require any sort of authentication.

Something wrong is here. If you setup your servlet container to ***require*** client authentication, you cannot have such open-for-all page, in that case auth handshake won't success for users without smartcard and they won't even see container error page - It will be browser error instead.

It can be done making container to ***allow*** client auth and making login page open to anonymous users and secure other pages by SpringSec. But I won't recommend this for smartcard-PKI app. Smartcard auth implies security importance and it's more reliable to have non-smartcard users to thrown out early on container handshake. In that case you still can have user-friendly Login page on another port with a "Login" button linked to your app.

If you need help with SpringSecurity setup, please add more info about problems to your post.

Comment: In Tomcat, you can set it to not need client authentication but to look for it by using `clientAuth="want"` on the `<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"` connector.

Answer (score 1):

From a configuration perspective, that looks fine. What is the error you're seeing? Are you seeing your UserDetailsService get invoked with the CN from X.509 cert?