# How to Secure the EJB3.0 Stateless Session Bean Web Services

Tags: web-services, ejb-3.0, jax-ws

I exposing EJB3.0 stateless session bean as web service using JAX-WS annotations and right now I'm using JBOSS5.1.0 GA as application server and JBOSSWS is generating the WSDL for me when I deploy the EAR.

Now I want to secure the web services by providing authentication and encryption-decryption on the SOAP messages. How do I can achieve that, Is there any annotations available for both in JAX-WS (or) can I achieve by doing any configuration at EJB level. I do not want to do secure web services with respect to JBOSS, because I want to deploy the same EAR in different application as well.

So please help me to build the generic EJB3.0 web services bean with the security implementation ., Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning SOAP WebServices, you can a lot of posts in this forum related to your question. In particular in [User authenticate in SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766811) I've mentioned that there several ways to authenticate the client.

Supposing that you want to authenticate the client by X.509 certificate. Then:

- For JBossWS refer [WS-SecurityOptions – X509 Certificate Token](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-WS-SecurityOptions#X509_Certificate_Token)
- For Metro/JAX-WS services refer [Using JAX-WS-Based Web Services with SSL](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-api-for-xml-web-services/using-jax-ws-based-web-services-wit.html)
- For Apache CXF refer [WS-Security](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html)
- For Spring Security refer [Spring Security With X.509 Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240212)